# Data deleted from PostGIS database while working and editing the spatial data

Tags: qgis, postgis, qgis-3, postgis-2.0

I have large amount of data and around 40 users working on it and doing editing in roads, rivers etc and updating attributes. I am using QGIS 3.26 for this. Today four main and large layer data disappeared one by one. I am not able to recognise the cause for this. My all missing layers were linear feature. I got the screenshot of statistics of database.
[image: Layers data deleted itself]

[image: Layer stats as shown in Postgresql]

Is there any hope to recover the data.

Comment: Well, first off you suspend daily backups and sequester the last full and incremental backups from before the data disappeared. Then you spin up a database clone to load the backups.

Comment: I didn't get what to do. I am less known to program language. Can you tell me the steps.

Comment: Not really. If you have a database, you have a database administrator. That person is responsible for making regular reliable backups, and performing restoration when necessary. If you are your own DBA, and you haven't made backups, then there is little hope of recovering the data. Either way, this isn't a GIS-centric task.

Comment: Thanks. i have a backup of 2 months ago.

Comment: The automated processes for most production systems are closer to weekly (for full backups) and daily for incremental. An HA mirror would not protect from an unwise DROP TABLE, but might for local corruption. You should probably make a post-failure snapshot, but don't let it overwrite the elderly backup. [dba.se] is the SE place to research restoration procedures (above and beyond documentation)